# Check if SetParent function worked?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a form and a panel within the form and this is my code to handle the setparent which works fine.

```
hWnd = FindWindow("MapleStoryClass", null);
Panel_Handle();
SetParent(hWnd, PanelHandle);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, (IntPtr)SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOP,
    -3, -25, 800, 600, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE);
```

The only question I have is how can I determine whether or not setparent worked via code? I understand I can visually check that setparent worked fine, but I need to input a check in my code to see if setparent worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using  the [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) WinApi function.

From above Link:

> If the window is a child window, the return value is a handle to the
>   parent window. If the window is a top-level window with the WS_POPUP
>   style, the return value is a handle to the owner window.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.   This function typically fails for
>   one of the following reasons:
>
> •The window is a top-level window that is unowned or does not have the
>   WS_POPUP style.
>     •The owner window has WS_POPUP style.

Answer (score 0):

since this is C# i would just say you can check if Panel.Parent is null

Panel.Parent is a reference to the parent of the Panel